# If the sum of squares of three prime numbers is a prime number, prove that atleast one of those three numbers is 3.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If the sum of squares of three prime numbers $a, b, c$ where $a, b, c \in \mathbb{N}$, is a prime number, prove that at least one of $a, b, c$ is equal to 3.

I've received a hint to assume that $\forall a, b, c \neq 3$ but sadly don't know how to use this fact, so I ask for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If none of them are $3$, then they are all of the form $3m+1$ or $3m+2$ (they don't all have to be the *same form*). Their squares are all of the form $3n+1$, so the sum of those squares is divisible by $3$. This is impossible.

Comment: +1 - I was just a few seconds away from providing a very similar answer.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of squares of three numbers none of which are divisible by $3$ is divisible by $3$. This is because the square of any number not divisible by $3$ is congruent to $1$ mod $3$. It follows that one of the primes must be divisible by, hence equal to, $3$.