# if a prime number is the sum of squares of three prime numbers, how can I show that at least one of them is 3?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider:

$$p = p_{1}^{2}\ + p_{2}^{2}\ + p_{3}^{2}$$

What I know so far:

From the square of a prime number greater than 5, I get an odd non-prime number, ending with 9 or 1.
The only way for ***p*** to be a prime number is when both $p_{2}^{2}$ & $p_{3}^{2}$ end with 9, then I sum 3*3 *which is*($p_{1}^{2}$) and I get a prime.

Is that right? If yes, how could I procceed?
I'd appreciate any hints or answers, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint:  if $p>3$ then $p^2\equiv 1 \pmod 3$.  The cases where $1$ or more of the primes in the sum are $=2$ must be handled separately.

Comment: @lulu You could post that as a hint/answer, because the OP asked for a hint specifically. This may be a dupe, though. Checking...

Comment: @lulu I'm sorry but, did you actually mean $p$? or it was $p_{1}^{2}$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  I'm searching for a duplicate as well, no luck so far.

Comment: @lulu Actually, $2^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ as well, so the case where one of the primes in the sum is $2$ does not need to be handled separately.

Comment: May be [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3422104/11619), @lulu?

Comment: @DeepakC  I meant any prime $p$, thinking of the summands $p_i$.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang  Good point.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen  Looks perfect.  Voting to close, accordingly.

Comment: @lulu Well, it probably does, I just wanted to check if my thoughts were correct and how I could answer it based on them. Thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $p_i$ is never $3$, then we can write it in the form of $p_i=3k+1$ or $3k+2$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$. As such, $p_i^2=9k^2+3\times2k+1$ or $9k^2+3\times4k+1$, as such $p=p_1^2+p_2^2+p_3^2=27k^2+3ak+3$, with $a\in\{6,8,10,16\}$, but since $p\equiv 0 \mod3$, then $p$ is not prime. As such at least one of the primes is $3$.